# Define environment variable in Dockerfile or docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile, 12factor

After reading the [config point of the 12 factor app](https://12factor.net/config) I decided to override my config file containing default value with environment variable.

I have 3 `Dockerfile`s, one for an API, one for a front-end and one for a worker. I have one `docker-compose.yml` to run those 3 services plus a database.

Now I'm wondering if I should define the environment variables in `Dockerfile`s or `docker-compose.yml` ? What's the difference between using one rather than another ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers):

> You can set environment variables in a service’s containers with the 'environment' key, just like with docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE ...

Also, you can use [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) in dockerfile to define a environment variable.

**The difference is:**

Environment variable define in `Dockerfile` will not only used in `docker build`, it will also persist into container. This means if you did not set `-e` when `docker run`, it will still have environment variable same as defined in `Dockerfile`.

While environment variable define in `docker-compose.yaml` just used for `docker run`.

Maybe next example could make you understand more clear:

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM alpine
ENV http_proxy http://123
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
app:
  environment:
    - http_proxy=http://123
```

If you define environment variable in `Dockerfile`, all containers used this image will also has the `http_proxy` as `http://123`. But the real situation maybe when you build the image, you need this proxy. But, the container maybe run by other people maybe not need this proxy or just have another http_proxy, so they had to remove the `http_proxy` in entrypoint or just change to another value in `docker-compose.yaml`.

If you define environment variable in `docker-compose.yaml`, then user could just choose his own http_proxy when do `docker-compose up`, `http_proxy` will not be set if user did not configure it `docker-compose.yaml`.

Comment: Thanks so I can define it in Dockerfile and if needed it can be overrided in docker-compose.yml if I understood correctly

Comment: Yes, define in `Dockerfile` will not only affect `docker build` but also `docker run`, define in `docker-compose` could override `docker run`.

Comment: michael your 2 line long sentence should be the correct answer